# Formatting MS Excel's table to draw a diagram of a certain form

Tags: microsoft-excel, diagrams

I have some data which consists of the list of documents, revisions of each document and the year of each revision. My goal is to represent this data with a diagram of the following form:

[image]

In the example above the list consists of three documents:

- "Document 1" was first published in 2011, and then republished in 2013 as revision 2.
- "Document 2" was first published in 2009, revised in 2010, then again in 2013 *twice* (so we place the number of the latest revision of that year which is 4), and the final revision as of 2017 was published in 2014.
- "Document 3" was published in 2011 and as of 2017 was never revised.

How should I arrange my data in the Excel table so that when I insert a diagram based on that table it would be of the desired form? Thank you very much in advance!

---

**[Edit]** For now the closest I got is this:

[image]

As you can see, it deviates from my sketch in several ways:

1. redundant blue lines at the beginning;
2. inaccurate range and step for the "year" axis;
3. coloring is too scattered;
4. numbers indicating the number of revision aren't drawn on lines;
5. right side legend is redundant;
6. no axis naming like **Year** and **Document**
7. documents are in the wrong order.

The crucial ones here are 1, 2 and, perhaps, 3. Items 4, 5, 6 can be easily fixed manually as a post-processing, and fixing 7th is about rearranging the table. Though it would be nice to have it done automatically.

Comment: 1) you can click on the blue lines and then set the filling to "no filling"

Comment: 2) click on the axis, and set min, max and step manually to 2009, 2017 and 1

Comment: 3) coloring: you need to do it by hand. click on each value and give it a new color. I do not know a nice way to do it automatically

Comment: 4) diagram tools -> layout -> data labels .... but for that you need to format your table differently. such that column A represents the version number

Comment: 6) also in "layout" there you can add the axis titles .. then just input them by hand

Comment: @masgo, thank you very much, it all works well! You might as well post it as an answer. One thing is still unresolved though: is there a way to change consecutive coloring from "left-to-right" to "right-to-left"? I need the latest revisions to be of the same color.

Comment: @masgo, oh, but then how would I delete the leftest lines?..

Comment: @masgo, is there a way to place years on the horizontal axis slantly? They started to overlap

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the blue line and chose format and format no line, no color
2. click on axis, select format and set the values as desired
3. ??? change the color by clicking on the bar select format and change color as desired
4. Click on add diagram elements, add data series text
5. Click on legend, press del
6. On diagram tools, select axis title and enter text
7. Click on the axis and revert the sequence

All these are very basic excel commands and you should look first for the help